# 8284 Clock Generator

Tags: clock

I am studying the [8284](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/124124/INTEL/8284A.html) clock generator and see how it works with the 8086.

But before I connect the two chips together, I want to verify the 8284 first.

So I placed the 8284 on the breadboard as follows:

[image]

Here are my questions, any help is appreciated:

1. I want to verify if the chip is working.  If I measure the output of CLK pin using multimeter, it always give me 2.1v.  (I know I need an oscilloscope, but I don't have one.  The only thing I tried is using arduinoscope, but it shows a constant 2.1v too).  Is it true buying a oscilloscope is the only way to "see it is working"?
2. I also tried to measure other pins, but they are all showing 2.1v or around 1v.  Which makes me wondering if my connections are actually wrong, is there any problem in my diagram above?

Comment: Yes, if you want to verify the waveforms that the chip is generating, you need something that can display waveforms -- an oscilloscope.

Comment: Not directly related, but you may have problems with these high frequencies on a breadboard. Keep an eye out for that.